# Take screenshots from other sessions in win32

Tags: c, windows, winapi, screenshot, usersession

I want to take screenshots from other logon sessions. Taking screenshot from the session that has ran the executable is okay but how can I do this with other sessions ?
Note: My executable is going to be executed as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access UIs from across session boundaries.  You will have to run a separate process in the target session, and then that process can capture the screenshot locally and then use an IPC mechanism of your choosing, such as a socket or pipe, to transmit the data to your main process.